# TypeScript: is it possible to define a generic class equivalent of a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-generics

## Question:

**Is it possible to define a class with properties whose names are not known in advance** (but are all of the the same type) **such that TS will know the properties of any instance of the class?**

If I were just trying to define a type, I'd do something like:

```
type SavedNumbers<TName extends string[]> = { [key in TName[number]]: number }

const foo: SavedNumbers<['a', 'b']> {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
}
```

However, I haven't been able to work out any equivalent method for defining a class.

---

## Attempted Solutions

Amongst many other things I tried:

1. Defining the class as implementing the mapped type, i.e.:

```
type SavedNumbers<TName extends string[]> = { [key in TName[number]]: number }

class Foo<
    TInstanceNames extends string[] = []
  > 
  implements SavedNumbers<TInstanceNames> {
  /* ... */
}
```

but of course `implements` only works with interfaces.

2. The same with `extends`; similar issue (restricted to classes).
3. Including the mapped type as part of the class declaration:

```
class Foo<TCustomNames extends string[] = []> {
  [key in TCustomNames[number]]: number
  /* ... */
}
```

but that also doesn't work.

---

## Alternative: Pass instances of the type to a function that adds the class methods.

E.g. first define:

```
function addMethods<T extends Record<string, number>>(x: T) {
  const plusOne = (a: number) => a + 1; 

  return Object.assign(x, {plusOne})
}
```

then we have:

```
const foo = addMethods({a: 0, b: 0})
foo.a // no error; TS knows property 'a' is defined on 'foo'; 
foo.b // ditto. 
foo.c // Error: "Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ a: number; b: number; } & { plusOne: (a: number) => number; }'."
    ~
```

However, with this approach, one cannot take advantage of all the conveniences afforded by using `class`.

Comment: `implements` works with **any type** that is *statically known* and has a qualified name or identifier, not just interfaces.

Comment: @kelsny does this offers a path to a solution? If so, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What conveniences are you talking about?  What's the use case?  Classes need statically-known keys, so you can't do this directly. You can write it indirectly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA2AXW), but I don't know if that meets your needs or not...

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the example; I always learn something interesting for your answers -- didn't know you could cast a class! I'm not sure what elements of the use case are relevant; however, I'd like to add a `with(key: string, value: number)` method that adds the key-value pair in such a way that TS knows all the keys that have been added such that trying to access an undefined property leads to a type error). I don't imagine the other methods / details would matter much.

Comment: Can you use my suggestion to meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining.  If not, please [edit] to have the example include the unmet need.  (And "in such a way that TS knows all the keys that have been added" seems out of scope here, since you can separate that from having a dynamic key of the class... e.g., just give the class a single `prop` of type `SavedNumbers<T>` and see if you can get that part done yourself. If so, great. If not, the answer to this question wouldn't help you.)

Comment: @jcalz I believe your suggestion would work (I'm just trying to work out how to have the returned type also know about the methods of the anonymous class); however, I was specifically interested in finding a way to store the saved values directly on the object as opposed to in a `SavedNumber<T>` prop; are you saying that this wouldn't be possible with your suggestion?

Comment: I’m not saying that, no.

Comment: Have you figured out the "I'm just trying to work out" thing?  If so I'll write up my suggestion as an answer.  If not, could you [edit] the example to demonstrate the use case you need?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment and didn't want to impose on your time. Looking at your example again, right now, gave me another idea that achieves what I was hoping for (I edited the example to add the approach). If you'd like to post that code / both as an answer I'll mark this answered. If there's some way that I can write it up but attribute the points to you, I'd be happy to do that as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you edit? I don’t see anything anywhere

Comment: [The TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEDsHtQJwUwIYGdLlAF2gVyXUC0EYYEBPUASwDN8AbW0UyLUAdwPUqX1C3AtShINANZxSSAFDpSABzwAxSJAA8AaVBwAHujjgAJtyToYFcAHMAfKAC8oAEpwAxpBj71AGghYAtgCM4GEsAbklJF3BjUCVoOydaZG4Ab0lQNNAI4xgsJ0wYAAozYwInOAA5BB84JAAuUCyzcwBtAF0ASlAU9O7KSPQS8srqgDoqVwBRBCcAC3z8kS8KDptrfPRpim5kfHBSNqaRFttKNuDQEFBAPg3Adl3AWAJAITJAeD-U9IBfSVf8bnA4VlB1TQ6PSGeomRqWQp9AYVKq1UBqVrLawxdQhMLhVBRGh2H5-GL5JoAIgQhK8hL8pNAhKchPaoUykFocGGtEg5nyVGGCA6FwAjBjIozmaz2Zy-DywAAmAUoJkstkc4ZOCWgADMYWmcHokD+rFctH0oCAA); I thought it saved changes.

Comment: And given that it doesn't (which would be really unfortunate, some sort of globally writable shared resource? how would you know the link actually showed what I said and not what some drive-by editor changed it to), and given that the link you've given me has been augmented with only "hellow world", *what specifically are we talking about?*  I'm happy to try to help but right now there doesn't seem to be anything to work with.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPBAKN) is what you want with `with`, but that's just a wild guess. What should we do here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why the link I posted doesn't show the edits I made. [Here's a link to a new playground](https://shorturl.at/BJX03).

Comment: So that version only makes the new properties available on the returned value, not on the original value... that is, `Bar` doesn't know anything about the properties, it's `Bar & {⋯}` that knows about it.  If you're happy with that, that's fine, but not what your question, as asked, seems to be about (at least to my eyes).  Indeed, `with()` isn't mentioned there either. Please do me a favor and [edit] the question to ask for exactly what you want, including any extra bits from these comments, and removing any distractions from that.  Then maybe I can post an appropriate answer.